# Contar ocorrência de eventos percorrendo colunas de um dataframe através de um loop for em R

Tags: r, loop, for, count

Olá, estou usando a função table() do R para contar as notas repetidas em cada coluna semestre (sem1, sem2,sem3...) de meu arquivo. Está funcionando corretamente, porém gostaria de fazer isso através de um **loop for** e se possível diretamente em um outro dataframe, sem a necessidade de abrir uma matriz para isso e converte-la ao final novamente.

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

```
datafile <- read.table("notasalunos.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE, sep = ";", header=TRUE)

matriz <- matrix(nrow=25,ncol=16)


matriz[,1] <- table(datafile$sem1)

matriz[,2] <- table(datafile$sem2)

matriz[,3] <- table(datafile$sem3)

matriz[,4] <- table(datafile$sem4)

matriz[,5] <- table(datafile$sem5)

matriz[,6] <- table(datafile$sem6)

matriz[,7] <- table(datafile$sem7)

matriz[,8] <- table(datafile$sem8)

matriz[,9] <- table(datafile$sem9)

matriz[,10] <- table(datafile$sem10)

matriz[,11] <- table(datafile$sem11)

matriz[,12] <- table(datafile$sem12)

matriz[,13] <- table(datafile$sem13)

matriz[,14] <- table(datafile$sem14)

matriz[,15] <- table(datafile$sem15)

newdatafile <- as.data.frame(t(matriz))
```

Comment: Olá, você pode editar a pergunta e colar o resultado de `dput(head(datafile, 40))`? Assim você ajuda quem esta aqui querendo te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar:

```
cols <- paste0("sem", 1:15)

as.data.frame(sapply(datafile[,cols], table))
```

o comando `sapply` faz o table em cada uma das colunas para você, ou seja, o `for`.

Comment: Legal mas neste caso a instrução cols <- paste0(c("sem", 1:15)) não gera sem1, sem2... mas sim: sem, 1, 2, 3.... Tens alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: corrigido. estava sem PC para testar

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!